# Beginner Coder...Having trouble with my if else statements

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, dom

```
[enter link description here][1]


   [1]: https://jsbin.com/zahidix/edit?html,js,output
```

Above the is the JS BIN which I've loaded my code in. I am having trouble if my if/else statement, for some reason I cannot get it to fail when I enter the number 0 and 13. Values 1-12 work just fine, but I purposely want it to fail after 12 and fail when 0 is entered. I am doing this because when I know this works I want the values to able to fill in the box colors when it reaches a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your if/else with:

```
if(v > 12 || v < 1) {
  alert(failed)
} else {
  alert(works)
}
```

[updated jsbin](https://jsbin.com/nanowedese/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (v > 12 ) {
    alert(failed);
} else {
    if (v <= 0) {
        alert(failed);
    } 
    else {
        alert(works);
    }
}
```